# I created a timer script and I want to add timerpickup to it - no errors found but the trigger does not work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I created a timer script and I want to add a timerpickup to it. No errors are  found, but the trigger does not work.

Well I have tried to do again the code in some other way but nothing append does not work either

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CountDownTimer : MonoBehaviour {
    public float addTime = 10.00f;
    float timeRemaining = 60.0f;

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if(other.gameObject.tag == "TimePickup")
        {
            //add time

            Destroy (GameObject.FindWithTag("TimePickup"));
            timeRemaining += addTime;  

        }
    }

    void Update () {
        timeRemaining -= Time.deltaTime;
    }


    void OnGUI(){
        if(timeRemaining > 0){
            GUI.Label(new Rect(325, 30, 200, 50), 
                      "Time Remaining : "+timeRemaining);
        }
        else{
            Application.LoadLevel ("Game Over");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You Should Not Capitalize Each And Every Single Word In Your English Sentences .....

Comment: Ok Tan You For The Advise I Am New And I have Some Times Problems With All.

Comment: Could be a few errors, have you set the Tag correctly? Did you set your collider as trigger? What do you mean by "does not work"? Is it not called at all, not entering your if?

Comment: i have insert this code to the maincamera on my gui system and i have insert this code to my timepickup to, i have set a box collider as trigger

Comment: But Wen I Try To Pickup Nothing Work But No errors To

Comment: When a collider "doesn't work", multiple reasons can be involved. 1. Are you sure the collider is set to trigger ? 2. Are you sure one of the two objects holds a `Rigidbody` ? 3. Are you sure the collision between the 2 objects can occur (check the layer matrix in the Physics settings)

Comment: Well i have checked and the two objects have the Rigidbody  and the timerPickup have the box collider and is check as trigger, and i have check on the matix in physics settings all is checked  only what is not checked there is pickup/Debris

Comment: @joaopires - good news, that is "all wrong"!  it's incredibly easy to do tiomers in Unity.  **Invoke("YourFunction", 3f);**  that's all there is to it.

Comment: Tank you for the replay, i am new on scripting can you show me how to aply it on my script pls.